# Найти количество студентов, у которых 3 семестра подряд одни пятерки

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть база данных, где вся таблица - это строки с оценками, каждая строка - это оценка по предмету, таким образом, строк столько, сколько оценок. Поля: `id_stud`, `gruppa`, `god`, `oz_q`(оценка), `fio`(фамилия), `sem`(семестр) и т.д.

Запрос на определение пользователей с  одними пятерками по каждому семестру такой, если правильно.

```
 select distinct id_stud,count(oz_q)
 from posl_oz
 where id_fak=128 and sem>=3
 group by id_stud,oz_q,god,sem
 having  min(oz_q)=5
```

как теперь найти пользователей у которых за 3 семестра подряд одни пятерки?
пробовал в where  sem in(sem,sem-1,sem-2). но так не правильно выводит.спасибо

Comment: ну вы и написали, однако же. Вы что-нибудь про нормализацию слышали? Да еще и названия полей транслитом. Кошмар какой

Comment: sem>=3 как у вас хранитсо это поле? куча лишних групировок.
Если я верно понял то where sem>=max(sem)-2
где max(sem) - текущий семестр.

Comment: ТС не из таких студентов. Инфа 100%.

Comment: название полей не я придумал, это универсистетская база данных в oracle.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваш запрос неверен, так в группировке присутствует оценка. Значит вы получите всех тех, у кого есть всего одна оценка - пятерка.
2. Экзамены могут быть сданы не все. Т.е. нужно проверять, что количество оценок совпадает с количеством экзаменов.

Когда вы напишете правильный запрос, то чтобы получить ответ на ваш вопрос, из этого запроса нужно убрать только лишь группировку по семестру.

[Группировка](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)